# ggplot multiple grouping bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, grouping, grouped-bar-chart

I would like to know how to get 9 grouping bar plot (3x3) together.

My CSV:

```
data <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6pArn8GL", sep = ";")
```

The 9 plots should be grouped according "Type" A to I.

Then each grouped bar plot should have the frequency on the y axis, the x axis is grouped by 1 pce to 6 pce and subdivided by year.

I have the following example on Excel (cf. image) and would like to create the same result on r with ggplot. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, reshape your data from wide to long format.

```
library(reshape2)
df.long<-melt(df,id.vars=c("ID","Type","Annee"))
```

Next, as during importing data letter X is added to variable names starting with number, remove it with `substring()`.

```
df.long$variable<-substring(df.long$variable,2)
```

Now use `variable` as x, `value` as y, `Annee` for fill and `geom_bar()` to get barplot. With `facet_wrap()` you can split data by `Type`.

```
ggplot(df.long,aes(variable,value,fill=as.factor(Annee)))+
   geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
   facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks is impressive but on my side I get an error message saying Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Comment: @Swiss12000 Are you using the code exactly the same way as my code? If not please add the code you use in your question.

Comment: indeed I need a mistake is perfectely working thanks for your help. I have the R Graphics Cookbook to learn ggplot but they don't mention how to do more complex graph. Did you learn ggplot everyday a bit or did you read an advanced books?

Comment: @Swiss12000 I learned by doing and by reading and answering questions here on SO

Comment: I found useful this documentation about melt: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: tidyr version please ?

Answer (score 10):

Using @Didzis reshaped data , here a lattice version:

```
barchart(value~variable|Type,
         groups=Annee,data=df.long,layout=c(3,3),
         between=list(3,3),
         axis=axis.grid,
         auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]