# How do I add 1 SD error bars to barplot in R

Tags: r

First, I did try to follow the link below (along with a bunch of other google efforts...):

[Grouped barplot in R with error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768219/grouped-barplot-in-r-with-error-bars)

My dataset is quite small (and R still greatly confuses me being new to any sort of programming).
My spatial data looks something like this with fake data:

```
Site1 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 3, 4, 8, 1, 4)
Site2 <- c(2, 4, 8, 8, 2, NA, 1, 2, 5)
Site3 <- c(5, NA, 4, NA, 8, 1, 3, 4 ,6)
my.data <- cbind(Site1, Site2, Site3)
my.data <- cbind(Site1, Site2, Site3)
my.data <- data.frame(a = c("during", "during", "during", "during",     "after", "after", "after", "after", "after"), my.data)
colnames(my.data) <- c("time", "GA", "GI", "DI")
```

I want to create a grouped barplot of the means of each site with error bars representing 1 standard deviation, where "during" and "after" are grouped by site (GA, GI, DI). I tried to do this by creating a data frame of means and plotting those. Which works great. Except I can't figure out how to add the error bars. I would appreciate any help. I know this is an elementary question but I am in baby steps when it comes to coding. So yeah.

Comment: So where exactly did you get stuck following the other answer? I don't see any reason not to close this as a duplicate. Show your code, describe exactly where you are having a problem. We're not here to code for you, we are here to answer specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it. Please note that I plotted the geom_errorbar using the code from the link you provided. And it seems to work fairly well!

Your problem was that your data was not shaped properly. Go through [this link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm) once

The code -

```
Site1 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 3, 4, 8, 1, 4)
Site2 <- c(2, 4, 8, 8, 2, NA, 1, 2, 5)
Site3 <- c(5, NA, 4, NA, 8, 1, 3, 4 ,6)
my.data <- cbind(Site1, Site2, Site3)
my.data <- cbind(Site1, Site2, Site3)
my.data <- data.frame(a = c("during", "during", "during", "during","after", "after", "after", "after", "after"), my.data)
colnames(my.data) <- c("time", "GA", "GI", "DI")

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
data <- reshape(my.data,direction="long", varying=names(my.data)[-1],
                timevar="Site", times=names(my.data)[-1], v.names="value")
df <- data %>% 
  group_by(Site,time) %>%
  summarize(Mean=mean(value,na.rm=T),SD=sd(value,na.rm=T))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Site,y=Mean,fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity",color="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SD,ymax=Mean+SD),width=0.2,position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help! i couldn't figure out what my problem was... reshaping the data was definitely the key to my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: the above code worked great for most of my data. However, when I use it for my full data set I get the following error after calling ggplot _Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in data.frame(x = c("DI", "DI", "GA",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 0_ . I wonder if it is because some of my sites have no data at all? As in the "during" bar is a zero (or actually an NA).

Comment: So I tested the code with fake data by adding NAs to a couple of sites, and your code still works. I just get a warning that some bars were not plotted (due to missing data). This is exactly correct, and with the fake dataset the code works. Just not with my real data... I checked the format/shaping of the dataset and it looks exactly like the fake data, except I have a few more sites in the real data. I'm so confused!

Comment: Ok I checked the code and I had a typo... so it works now!