# Adding standard deviation to barplot() in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, standard-deviation

In R I have the following dataframe:

```
  Group mean  sd
1     1   21.2  5.202563
2     2   28.4  6.113737
3     3   21.8  2.529822
```

I would like to create a barplot with the means and the standard deviations as arrows on top of the means like this example:
[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
barCenters <- barplot(height = Ymeans12stdev$mean,main = "Average Time per Group",
                  xlab = "Group", ylab = "Time")
```

However, I am not succeeding in adding the standard deviation bars. Can anyone solve this ? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped barplot in R with error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768219/grouped-barplot-in-r-with-error-bars)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with base R, you can use the function arrows() :

```
barCenters <- barplot(height = Ymeans12stdev$mean,
                      main = "Average Time per Group", xlab = "Group", ylab = "Time")
arrows(barCenters, Ymeans12stdev$mean-Ymeans12stdev$sd,
       barCenters, Ymeans12stdev$mean+Ymeans12stdev$sd,angle=90,code=3)
```

the argument `angle=90` specifies to draw "flat" arrows (i.e. a horizontal bar on top of a vertical one) and the argument `code=3` specifies to draw arrows on both ends of the vertical line. You can add the argument `length` to increase/reduce the size of the horizontals bars of the arrows.