# ggplot geom_bar combining in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to combine two `ggplot barchart` next to each other into one graph:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Year,lossratio1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="blue") 

ggplot(data, aes(Year, lossratio2) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="red", fill="red")
```

Note:

- x-axis is the `year`
- y-axis is `lossratio1` and `lossratio2`.

Barchart fill follows the `lossratio` respectively.

Comment: Please show some data, eg. using `dput(head(data, 10))`. But I think there is already an answer, see this post for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158461/grouped-bar-plot-in-ggplot

Comment: Year=c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016) lossratio1=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.95,1) lossratio2=(0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9) data=data.frame(Year,lossratio1,lossratio2) The plot when I use this: ggplot(data)+geom_bar(aes(Year,lossratio1),data,stat="identity",colour="blue",fill="blue)+geom_bar(aes(Year,lossratio2),data,stat="identity",colour="red",fill="red"). This gives plot where the overlapping areas are in red. Where should I put the position="dodge"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to melt your data first, then you can set position = "dodge", like so:

```
library(reshape)
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars='Year')

ggplot(data.m, aes(Year, value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```