# Barplots with grouping by multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot that looks like this in ggplot2:

[image]

Here's a dummy dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = exp(rnorm(6)),
                  f1 = factor(c("a","b","c","c","d","d")),
                  f2 = factor(c("","","1","2","1","2")))
```

And a non-working example:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=f1, y=x, fill= f2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", rep("green",4)))
```

[image]

I could do this by brute force in `base` graphics, but I'm unsure how to go about it in `ggplot2`, and I need to use `ggplot2` so as to keep this plot consistent with the theme I'm using throughout the project.

So how do I make the factors `1` and `2` go side by side?  And how do I center the labels like I have in the drawing?  And how do I make the colors behave?

Comment: You may be looking for `position_dodge` instead of the default stacking.  For multiple centered labels see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337286/2461552).  Other answers to that question may be useful, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a barplot with grouped bars, a question that was answered  here: [Grouped bar plot in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158461/grouped-bar-plot-in-ggplot)

`fill` only determines the colors, not the grouping, this is why you get blue and green bars for c and d.