# Show trend on the grouped bar plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, trend

This is an extension of the already discussed question (I am copying the perfect data example and solution by jakub from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162330 )

Data:

```
raw <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=L8cEKcxS",sep=",")
raw[,2]<-factor(raw[,2],levels=c("Verygood","Bad","Good","VeryGood"),ordered=FALSE)
raw[,3]<-factor(raw[,3],levels=c("Very Bad","Bad","Good","Very Good"),ordered=FALSE)
raw[,4]<-factor(raw[,4],levels=c("Very Bad","Bad","Good","Very Good"),ordered=FALSE)
raw=raw[,c(2,3,4)]
freq=table(col(raw), as.matrix(raw)) # get the counts of each factor level
```

ggplot + mutliple grouping bar

```
Names=c("Food","Music","People")     # create list of names
data=data.frame(cbind(freq),Names)   # combine them into a data frame
data=data[,c(5,3,1,2,4)]             # sort columns
# melt the data frame for plotting
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars='Names')
# plot everything
ggplot(data.m, aes(Names, value)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
```

The only addition I am struggling to make is to add a fitted line (third degree polynomial) to show the trend for each category as variable changes from "very bad" to "very good"

[image: image with desired fitted line]

Plotting the trend seems to be an issue.

Comment: To plot the trend by category you probably want to use a facet which separates the categories so the trend line calculates separately for each group: `ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, value)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Names)`. Then you just need to define your trend line

Comment: Agreed with @Mako212, but you no longer need dodging. Use e.g. `ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + facet_grid(~Names) + geom_smooth(aes(group = 1))`. Will not look good with few categories.