# Pivot Data and Grouped bar Plot in R

Tags: r

I am an R neewbie, so apologies if my question is too basic or if I've violated a forum rule.

I have data in 2-columns. The second column contains the sex (Female-1 and male-2). Column 'a' (first column) contains answer responses to a question which range from (0,1,2,3,4).

How can I get a bar plot of the count of answers, grouped by sex. I am able to do this in excel but I haven't been able to do so in R. In the first instance, I'm unable to transform the data to be usable for plotting. I tried dplyr, etc.

```
a   Sex
1   1
0   2
4   1
2   2
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   1
2   1
4   2
4   1
2   1
1   2
0   1
2   2
3   1
0   1
4   1
2   1
0   1
1   1
2   2
2   1
1   2
1   2
1   1
0   1
1   1
3   
0   1
3   1
4   1
2   2
0   1
1   1
1   2
0   1
3   1
3   1
2   1
1   1
1   1
0   1
0   2
4   1
0   2
0   2
0   2
2   1
2   1
0   2
1   1
4   1
0   1
2   1
0   2
1   2
2   2
0   1
0   1
1   1
1   1
2   2
1   1
0   1
0   2
1   2
0   1
0   1
3   1
0   1
0   2
1   2
0   2
0   1
2   
4   2
0   1
1   1
2   2
1   1
4   2
1   1
4   2
0   1
4   2
0   1
2   2
2   1
4   1
2   2
1   1
1   1
2   1
2   1
1   1
3   2
1   1
1   1
2   1
0   2
3   2
2   1
0   1
1   2
2   2
0   2
3   2
2   1
0   1
1   1
1   2
1   1
1   1
0   2
1   
0   1
2   1
3   1
0   2
2   1
2   1
0   2
2   1
0   1
0   1
4   1
2   1
2   1
2   1
3   2
2   2
3   1
1   1
2   2
1   1
0   2
2   1
1   2
1   2
0   1
1   2
0   1
2   1
2   1
1   1
2   2
1   1
0   2
2   1
1   1
2   1
2   1
4   2
1   1
0   1
0   1
3   1
3   1
2   1
0   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
2   1
1   1
2   1
2   1
2   1
1   2
2   1
2   1
3   1
0   1
1   2
2   2
1   1
2   1
0   2
0   1
2   1
0   1
0   1
0   1
3   2
2   2
1   2
1   1
1   1
4   1
3   2
2   1
3   1
0   1
1   2
0   1
3   
2   2
1   1
3   2
1   2
1   1
2   2
2   2
1   2
0   1
2   2
1   1
2   2
0   2
2   2
0   1
0   1
3   2
3   2
1   3
2   1
0   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
4   2
2   2
2   1
0   2
1   2
1   1
0   2
3   1
3   1
2   1
2   1
2   2
1   1
0   1
2   1
0   1
4   1
0   2
0   1
3   1
1   2
0   1
0   1
0   2
2   1
2   2
1   2
2   1
4   1
2   2
2   1
2   1
1   2
3   1
0   1
1   1
1   1
4   1
0   2
3   
0   
0   2
2   1
3   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
0   1
1   2
0   1
3   1
3   2
3   1
0   1
0   1
2   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   1
2   2
3   1
1   2
1   1
```

Output I'm trying to achieve:

[image: plot]

Comment: Look at the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158461/grouped-bar-plot-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should get you started:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  count(Sex = ifelse(Sex == 1, "Female", "Male"), a) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = n, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thank you! the code works perfectly. However, when I want to plot other columns, say column 'b' (i.e. Same as above bar plot of the count of answers in column 'b', grouped by sex) and modify the code to read column 'b' (wherever there is now 'a') the output gets skewed (i.e. all bars plot to the maximum). What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: I changed y=nn in ggplot(aes(x = a, y = nn, fill = Sex)) and the command works for all columns

Comment: Can you post an example of your `df` with other columns? `count` by definition summarises the data, so you may be losing observations with that, am not sure - there could be other approaches

Comment: Thank you for your response. The df is available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3cd43dehlmz9d7/Analysis_Share.csv?dl=1

Comment: Get an error when accessing, can you copy paste just first few rows and all columns in your original post?

Comment: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p Sex\\
1 3 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 3 3 4 2 1\\
               1 2
4 4 4 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 1\\