# Make two geom_bar() plots base on different columns in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 Year     Women       Men
1 2013    145169      889190
2 2014    119064      849778
3 2015    210107     1079592
4 2016    221217     1427639
5 2017    205000     1692592
6 2018    273721     1703456
7 2019    434407     2010493
```

I want to make a geom_bar, where x is a year and every year has two bars for a number from Women and Men. I have found a solution where this table should looks different, but I'm wondering if there is an option to work with this one. Thank You for any help :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? Do you have any code? Pleae include the code in the question as well and google "ggplot2 data long to wide and stacked barplot"

Comment: it's pivot from wide to long... something like the answer below should be ok. you don't need the whole tidyverse package.. tidyr and ggplot2 are enough

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouped bar plot in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158461/grouped-bar-plot-in-ggplot)

Comment: Thank You very much for help, the answer below works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -c(Year,Sl), values_to = "Value", names_to = "Name") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Value, fill = Name))+geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

## Data

```
df = structure(list(Sl = 1:7, Year = 2013:2019, Women = c(145169L, 
119064L, 210107L, 221217L, 205000L, 273721L, 434407L), Men = c(889190L, 
849778L, 1079592L, 1427639L, 1692592L, 1703456L, 2010493L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```