# ggplot can not group bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

Who can tell me why ggplot can't give me grouped bars?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(labels), y = srednia, dodge=factor(group))) + 
    labs(title = gen, size=3)+ ylab("Fold change")+ xlab("Linnia komórkowa") +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(group)),stat="identity",position ="dodge") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=minus, ymax=plus))
```

[image]

Grouped bars I means something like this (paint art):
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by grouped bars? Stacked bars?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and a description of the desired output.

Comment: Seems to me that you probably should try `x=factor(group)` and `dodge= factor(lables)` instead of the other way round. But it's not entirely clear what you mean by grouped bars, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303573/ggplot-multiple-grouping-bar

Comment: @shadow The problem is that x must = labels and bars have to be grouped by groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can achieve this by changing the scale for the x axis. Here's a reproducible example and a possible solution.

```
# packages
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)
# generate data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(labels=LETTERS[1:6], 
                 group=rep(1:3, each=2),
                 srednia=runif(6))
# limits for x axis
mylims <- head(unlist(dlply(df, .(group), function(x) c(levels(factor(x$labels)), "space"))), -1)
# additional space between groups
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(labels), y = srednia, dodge=factor(group))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(group)),stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=mylims, breaks=levels(factor(df$labels)))
# removing space within group
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(labels), y = srednia, dodge=factor(group))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(group)),stat="identity", width=1) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=mylims, breaks=levels(factor(df$labels)))
```