# R, shiny: ggplot, geom_bar, order of bars by their fill argument when fill is a reactive

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, geom-bar

I am struggling with the order of bars in ggplot. To keep things simple: here is the code I am using to create the plot:

```
plot_data <- data() %>% 
  filter(Name %in% input$polymers)
print(plot_data)
ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = ID_Polymer, y = value), position = position_dodge(width = 1))  +
  geom_bar(aes_string( fill=razeni()), position = position_dodge(width = 1), stat="identity", color="white")+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=21))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=21))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(input$title_text_box_id) + 
  labs(x = "", y = input$ylabel_text_box_id) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = ID_Polymer, y = value,Group=Polymer,label=value), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),vjust=2, size=5,colour = "white", fontface = "bold") +
  scale_fill_tableau("Tableau 10")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c(xpopisky()))#puts a reactive in x labels
```

fill argument is reactive, that the user chooses in the shiny app. 
The results looks like this:
[image]

I would like the two blue bars and the two red bars be side by side, like at this post [ggplot can not group bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403462/ggplot-can-not-group-bars)

The tricky thing is, that the fill arguments changes by user input from shiny app and so must change the order of bars.

something like: 
`aes_string(dodge = razeni())` or `aes_string(order = razeni())`

I hope the issue is clear and I will be glad for any suggestions on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, If anyone struggles with the same issue, here is my solution, that worked for my case:
first I create a reactive `data.frame` with the data. Then I make a chosen column of the table a factor ("ID_Polymer" in my case), I set the levels of the factor and I use `order()` function with an argument that is selected by the user (which is done by in `shinyUI()` by `selectInput` `input$groupby`). The code goes like this:

```
dataforplot <- reactive({
  plot_data <-  data() %>% 
    filter(Name %in% input$polymers) 
    plot_data$ID_Polymer <- factor(plot_data$ID_Polymer, 
          levels =plot_data$ID_Polymer[ order(plot_data[[input$groupby]])])
    return(plot_data) # so it returns the data frame and not only the column  plot_data$ID_Polymer
})
```

and than I just create a ggplot:

```
plotInput <- reactive({
    ggplot(data = dataforplot(), aes(x = ID_Polymer, y = value), position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
})
```

This solution worked for me so I hope it helps.