# 3 Data Frames on same ggplots

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

I have looked through a lot of examples but haven't found one that matches my specific problem.

I have 3 DataFrames with the same column headers and 18 rows of data. The Row headers are the same name. Only the data is different between them. Example below:

```
                   tLap                   sLap            
                   mean       std         mean        std    
BCornerExit                                                          
T1             8.605985  0.457682   411.187591  10.113426     
T2            18.140000  0.235266   997.824691  20.041654      
T3            19.873673  0.428377  1144.357143  35.527184      
T4            21.810192  0.425416  1302.209615  34.869531      
T5            36.183654  0.228696  2437.650000   8.421762
```

There are 30 columns with 2 sub columns for each one.

My 3 Data Frames are called:

```
df_Entry
df_Apex
df_Exit
```

I need to create a plot for each main column which has 3 bars per turn (i.e T1)
Each of these bars are the 'Mean' Column in the DF and then have error bars as the 'std' columns for each bar.

I have no experience with GGPlot so please be patient with slow responses if I'm trialing answers. [image]

Above is a previous example I made with MatPlotLib and much worse code before I used DataFrames. But it looks almost identical to what I need.

If I've missed any information please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so what have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Sadly Tom I'm at a loss of where to start. I was looking at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303573/ggplot-multiple-grouping-bar but couldn't apply it to my own

Comment: Do you require ggplot in particular?  This shouldn't be too hard just using pandas itself.

Comment: Yeah I was requested to use ggplot :/ I did explain to them I'd never used it but it's what they wanted.